# Android : application not usable after the device goes idle

Tags: android, device, sleep-mode

We have released an application recently and few of the users are reporting that the application is not usable after the device goes idle when the app is in open state.

We have done R & D on this issue and we have even called super.onResume() on onResume method which was one of the suggestion from other posts.

**Additional information : when the device goes idle, below are the state of the app

- no threads are running
- no HTTP server calls are made
- app running based on the data in the internal SQLite database

**

Any thoughts on the root cause of the issue and solution?

It would great to find the root cause when we know the list of things changed/state changes when an android device goes idle?

Comment: What does it mean "the application is not usable"? It crashes?

Comment: what are you doing in onPause/onStop and onRestart/onStart/onResume ??

Comment: I think problem may be with database/cursor , possibly you db object/cursor  is closed and you try to access ?

Comment: got some long Loading bar or the performance of the app would be very slow

Comment: Randomly it crashes the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle, we found that the issue was raised in devices with latest versions, in which the method "onResume" is not directly called when the app is opened from background mode.

Instead, the onCreate method is called and also it initializes the static variables.

So kindly make sure to check the values of the variables which are necessary for the view.